# Intel Xeon E5 2680 x 2 / NVIDIA GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] computer will boot up on Live USB perfectly, but only boots to black screen with full install

Tags: boot, drivers, video

Ubuntu 22.04 freshly installed a month or so ago.

I then started installing aplications and utilities. The utility application `indicator-multiload` caused my GUI to be unusable. I tried for a week or so to rectify this, before freshly installing Ubuntu 22.04 again.

I didn't install `indicator-multiload` this time, much as I'd like to. I've found it extremely handy for the last 10 years.

I was then able to boot successfully for a couple of weeks. I shut it down last Thursday evening, and when I tried to boot it up on Friday morning, it booted into a blank screen (with the monitor going into standby mode because there was no signal).

Since it had only been a couple of weeks since I had installed Ubuntu 22.04, I thought no problem, I'll install it again. The installation process from a USB thumb drive went perfectly, including the installer detecting the earlier installation of Ubuntu 22.04. At the end of this installation, and rebooting, it booted into a blank screen again.

Since then, I have only been able to use the computer by booting into the USB thumb drive, which means I am able to use the computer, but can't install any other applications, install browser plugins, keep web cookies, synchronise bookmarks, etc.

I tried Ctrl+Alt+F4 from the blank screen, and it works. I tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, and "All the available drivers are already installed".

It booted into a blank screen again.

Ctrl+Alt+F4 then `sudo apt purge nvidia*` then `sudo reboot`.

This was a little bit more exciting, because I got a Ubuntu graphic, before the screen went blank and the monitor went into standby mode.

I'm now stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried re-establishing the bootable USB to the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Comment: I'm curious... What kind of nvidia gpu do you have? Do you regularly use the proprietary or nouveau graphics driver? When you boot onto your USB, could you try in a terminal....  nvidia-smi  for info. What graphic interface do you use, Mate, KDE, Gnome,... Is Indicator Multiload is a GNOME-Applet

Comment: @ChuckLiu I downloaded the image that I used 2 or 3 weeks ago.

Comment: @Nishnabe What kind of nvidia gpu do you have?
About... says "Graphics NV138". I've just got this computer back repaired, and I think the graphics card was replaced with another low-end NVidia one.

Do you regularly use the proprietary or nouveau graphics driver?
I have no preference. I use whatever the installation uses. At the moment, I just want the thing to run.

Comment: @Nishnabe When you boot onto your USB, could you try in a terminal.... nvidia-smi for info.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390         # version 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-418-server  # version 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450-server  # version 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470         # version 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

Comment: @Nishnabe sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470-server  # version 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525         # version 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525-server  # version 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535         # version 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535-server  # version 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-510         # version 510.60.02-0ubuntu1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-510-server  # version 510.47.03-0ubuntu3
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: @Nishnabe 
What graphic interface do you use, Mate, KDE, Gnome
Ubuntu default. I understand it to be Gnome.

Is Indicator Multiload is a GNOME-Applet
Hm. I don't know. Here's a search result: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=indicator-multiload&ia=web

Comment: What if you were to rephrase your question, and add the GPU specs, driver specs and your computer brand into the body of your question via editing it. And Edit the title to say, " (enter brand of computer and operating system names here) will boot up on Live USB perfectly, but only boots to black screen with full install"

Comment: Can you edit your grub and remove the quiet splash so you can perhaps see more of what is happening in real-time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-create your bootable USB from [22.04 LTS](https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/) with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).

Then re-install the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on your machine.

Comment: "System Requirements:

Windows 8 or later. Once downloaded, the application is ready to use."

I don't easily have access to Windows 8 or later. Is this a trial-and-error approach? If it seems likely to work for some reason, I will take the time to find and borrow a Windows machine, but I'd like to know the reason before investing the time and effort. Cheers

Comment: I use Ventoy or Startup Disk Creator for Linux systems to create live USB's for Linux. If that is what you want or need to do. You don't have to use windows rufus program.